# Unintentionally Left Out Authors

Tags: authorship, poster

I'm presenting a poster at a conference in the coming months and I unintentionally left out authors (the senior authors) on my work due to my lack of familiarity with the submission program on the website. Unfortunately, I did not go back to correct this until it was too late and the deadline for adjustments had passed.

I'm now faced with presenting the poster without all authors listed on the poster. I'm fairly embarrassed that I let this happen. I've reached out to the organizers and was told no more adjustments can be made. How do I handle it from here? Do I just disclose during presentation that I unintentionally left them out and credit them at that point?

Comment: Did you contact the author who you left out? And, what did she say? If this had happened, then why did you register for the poster presentation?

Comment: Add them with a sharpie marker?

Comment: You probably don't need to worry.  Posters are typically not a big deal; certainly "getting credit" for a poster won't matter career-wise to anyone who is not still a grad student (unless you win a prize for it, I suppose).  Just tell your collaborators what you've written here.

Comment: @Coder It looks like there were two, or possibly more, left out ("author**s**"). Of course, your comment still applies.

Answer (score 19):

It is what it is, at least as far as the official program is concerned -- tell the missing author about it and apologize.

What's more important in practice is that all authors are listed on the actual poster you will be presenting. That's what people really see and will notice, so make sure it is complete.

Comment: Agreed. The conference abstract book will be inaccurate, but as long as all authors are listed on the poster itself, you're fine.

Comment: From a CV perspective, it will be harder for the omitted authors to prove that they were part of the poster. That said, this is the best you can do. Definitely apologize!

Comment: Presumably if they are senior researchers, they won't particularly care about being an n-th author on some poster. Even as a graduate student I don't think I would care about getting left off of some n-th author conference proceeding and only include them in my most painfully complete CV.